# Up, up and away in a Retro Rocket

Tags: c#, rags-to-riches

I have seen the Writings on the wall...

1. [Retro Rocket ASCII Art](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/65040/18427)
2. [Nested for-loop art](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26247602/1214743)
3. [Print the Retro Rocket](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38622/9435)
4. Maybe a golfed C# answer from me

But I took this relatively serious and created a `VerticalRocket` class that I would like reviewed, kind of like a little "am I getting better at writing code" project/review experience (granted this was done while waiting for code to compile and queries to run).

What can I learn from this experience?

```
class VerticalRocket
{
    private int _FuselageSections = 2;
    public int FuselageSections
    {
        get
        {
            return _FuselageSections;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 100 && value > 0)
            {
                _FuselageSections = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public List<string> rocketPartsList = new List<string>();

    private string Divider = "+=*=*=*=*=*=*+";

    private List<string> upDesigns = new List<string>
    {
          @"|../\..../\..|"
        , @"|./\/\../\/\.|"
        , @"|/\/\/\/\/\/\|"
    };

    private List<string> downDesigns = new List<string>
    {
          @"|\/\/\/\/\/\/|"
        , @"|.\/\/..\/\/.|"
        , @"|..\/....\/..|"
    };
    private List<string> NoseParts = new List<string>
    {
          @"      /\"
        , @"     /**\"
        , @"    //**\\"
        , @"   ///**\\\"
        , @"  ////**\\\\"
        , @" /////**\\\\\"
    };

    private List<string> BoosterParts = new List<string>
    {
          @"    //**\\"
        , @"   ///**\\\"
        , @"  ////**\\\\"
        , @" /////**\\\\\"
    };
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Generic Rocket with 2 Fuselage Sections.
    /// </summary>
    public VerticalRocket()
    {
        rocket(FuselageSections);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// creates a rocket with specified number of Fuselage sections
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sections">Number of Fuselage Sections Desired</param>
    public VerticalRocket(int sections)
    {
        FuselageSections = sections;
        rocket(FuselageSections);
    }

    public List<string> Fuselage(bool diamondShape)
    {
        List<string> fuselage = new List<string>();

        if (diamondShape)
        {
            foreach (string line in upDesigns)
            {
                fuselage.Add(line);
            }
            foreach (string line in downDesigns)
            {
                fuselage.Add(line);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string line in downDesigns)
            {
                fuselage.Add(line);
            }
            foreach (string line in upDesigns)
            {
                fuselage.Add(line);
            }
        }
        return fuselage;
    }

    public List<string> Nose()
    {
        List<string> nose = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in NoseParts)
        {
            nose.Add(line);
        }
        return nose;
    }

    public List<string> Booster()
    {
        List<string> booster = new List<string>();
        foreach (string line in BoosterParts)
        {
            booster.Add(line);
        }
        return booster;
    }

    public void rocket(int sections)
    {
        bool wantDiamond = sections % 2 == 0 ? true : false; //this will keep the X at the bottom

        rocketPartsList.AddRange(Nose());
        rocketPartsList.Add(Divider);
        for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
        {
            rocketPartsList.AddRange(Fuselage(wantDiamond));
            wantDiamond = !wantDiamond;
            rocketPartsList.Add(Divider);
        }
        rocketPartsList.AddRange(Booster());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = "";
        foreach (string line in rocketPartsList)
        {
            output += line + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

### Note

Up-To-Date code can be found on my [Github Repo](https://github.com/malachi26/RetroRocketASCII)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Naming**

Methodnames should be made out of verbs or verb phrasese, so `Nose()`, `Booster` and so on, arent't good names for methods. They would make good names for readonly properties.

Fieldnames should be named using `camelCasing` casing.
Methodnames should be named using `PascalCasing`.

**Scope**

All your methods are `public` which isn't necessary at all. The only method which needs to be public is the overridden `ToString`.

Example code to blow up your code

```
VerticalRocket rocket = new VerticalRocket(2);
rocket.rocketPartsList = null;
Console.WriteLine(rocket.ToString());
```

This shouldn't be possible ;-)

So watch the scope.

**Flow**

As you have the `FuselageSections` property, this is the only part of your code, which can change the output of the `ToString()` method. Therefor I would expect that inside the `ToString()` method the composition of the rocket would take place. I wouldn't call a method `rocket()` to actually build the rocket after changing the property.

Also, if I really would call the `rocket()` method after changing the property, a really strange rocket would be built, as you don't clear the `rocketPartsList` field.

So I see 3 possibilities

1. Rebuild the rocket if the property is changed (bad, as properties should return as fast as possible)
2. Rebuild the rocket inside the `ToString()` method
3. rename the `rocket()` method to something more meaningful like `Rebuild()`, leave it public and skip the property.

I would go with number 3, but a little bit different. I would rename `rocket` to `Build(int)` and define it as `private` and then introduce a new method `public Rebuild(int)` which is only calling `Build()`.

**Refactoring**

As the methods `Nose()`, `Booster()` shouldn't be accessible from the outside, changing the scope to `private` should be done. But if they are private we can just skip them, as they only return a new `List<String>` representing the private fields.

These `List<String>` fields are a little over the head also. You don't need the `List`'s as you don't use any of its methods. A String array would be a better fit.

The `divider` field should be a const.

You should use constructor chaining as well.

> ```
> public VerticalRocket()
> {
>     rocket(FuselageSections);
> }
> ```

should be

```
public VerticalRocket():this(FuselageSections)
{}
```

After implementing this and also the points of [ferada's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/67474/29371) we would get the following

```
class VerticalRocket
{
    private const int initialFuselageSections = 2;
    private const string divider = "+=*=*=*=*=*=*+";

    private List<string> rocketPartsList = new List<string>();

    private String[] upDesigns = 
    {
      @"|../\..../\..|"
    , @"|./\/\../\/\.|"
    , @"|/\/\/\/\/\/\|"
    };

    private String[] downDesigns = 
    {
      @"|\/\/\/\/\/\/|"
    , @"|.\/\/..\/\/.|"
    , @"|..\/....\/..|"
    };

    private String[] noseParts = 
    {
      @"      /\"
    , @"     /**\"
    , @"    //**\\"
    , @"   ///**\\\"
    , @"  ////**\\\\"
    , @" /////**\\\\\"
    };

    private String[] boosterParts = 
    {
      @"    //**\\"
    , @"   ///**\\\"
    , @"  ////**\\\\"
    , @" /////**\\\\\"
    };

    public VerticalRocket()
        : this(initialFuselageSections)
    { }

    public VerticalRocket(int sections)
    {
        Build(sections);
    }

    public List<string> GetFuselage(bool diamondShape)
    {
        List<string> fuselage = new List<string>();

        if (diamondShape)
        {
            fuselage.AddRange(upDesigns);
            fuselage.AddRange(downDesigns);
        }
        else
        {
            fuselage.AddRange(downDesigns);
            fuselage.AddRange(upDesigns);
        }
        return fuselage;
    }

    public void ReBuild(int sections)
    {
        Build(sections);
    }

    private void Build(int sections)
    {
        if (sections > 100 && sections <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("sections");
        }

        bool wantDiamond = sections % 2 == 0;

        rocketPartsList.Clear();
        rocketPartsList.AddRange(noseParts);
        rocketPartsList.Add(divider);

        for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
        {
            rocketPartsList.AddRange(GetFuselage(wantDiamond));
            wantDiamond = !wantDiamond;
            rocketPartsList.Add(divider);
        }

        rocketPartsList.AddRange(boosterParts);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rocketPartsList);
    }

}
```

You could also build the nose of the rocket by using only the first 2 items of the `noseParts` and add the `boosterParts`.

Answer (score 7):

- I don't like that the `FuselageSections` silently discards out of
  bounds values, throwing an exception would be better.
- Maybe there are shorter ways, but `Fuselage` can use `AddRange` as
  well:

  ```
  if (diamondShape)
  {
      fuselage.AddRange(upDesigns);
      fuselage.AddRange(downDesigns);
  }
  else
  {
      fuselage.AddRange(downDesigns);
      fuselage.AddRange(upDesigns);
  }
  ```
- `wantDiamond` can just be

  ```
  bool wantDiamond = sections % 2 == 0;
  ```

  and that (`foo ? true : false` or the reverse) is something I'll
  always fix if I see it somewhere.
- `ToString` can just be

  ```
  return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, rocketPartsList);
  ```

  instead.
- `Nose`, `Booster` can all just create a copy with the `List`
  constructor, i.e.

  ```
  return new List<string>(BoosterParts);
  ```

  and so on.

Otherwise looks fine; if it was actually part of a larger program I'd
move the parts itself into classes and have them output (`ToString`)
themselves instead.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to point these things out.  the Ternary thing, I do that all the time... and people tell me what you told me, all the time... lol

Comment: thank you for this answer. It made me miss my train station while reading ;-(

Comment: @Heslacher my apologies, glad it helped though; you have good points as well.